# Objective C Pointers problem with cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, pointers, cocos2d-iphone

What im trying to do is to initialize a b2Body dynamically for any object that i have. Here is the code:

```
b2Body * mallet1;

[self setMalletProperties: &blockBodyDef : mallet1];

-(void) setMalletProperties:(b2BodyDef *)body :(b2Body *) mallet {
body->type = b2_dynamicBody;

mallet = world->CreateBody(body);
b2Vec2 newLocation = b2Vec2([self getScreenSize].width/2/PTM_RATIO,[self getScreenSize].height * .2833/PTM_RATIO);
//b2Vec2 newLocation = b2Vec2(x, y);
mallet->SetTransform(newLocation,0.0f);

mallet->SetFixedRotation(true);

b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
b2CircleShape dynamicCircle;
dynamicCircle.m_radius = 0.85;        
fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicCircle;  
fixtureDef.restitution =0.1f;
fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.0f;
mallet1Fixture = mallet->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

if ([self getScreenSize].width == 768) {
    dynamicCircle.m_radius = 1.75;
}
}
```

Its not working properly, cause its not putting the body that i created into the variable mallet1. What am i doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void) setMalletProperties:(b2BodyDef *)body :(b2Body **) mallet {
body->type = b2_dynamicBody;

*mallet = world->CreateBody(body);
 ...
}
```

Your current code doesn't provide a way to access the same reference to mallet again.

Alternatively you could change the method signature like so:
`-(b2Body*) setMalletProperties:(b2BodyDef *)body` and include a `return mallet;` at the end

Comment: It shows this error on: *mallet1 = world->CreateBody(body);
No viable overloaded '='

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't seen that error before. A quick Google tells me that it's something to do with concurrency. Is your program multi-threaded?

Comment: I've posted another possible solution

Comment: I'm using cocos2d, and as far as i know its not working multi threaded. If i try to asigned to mallet using the adress as: &mallet = world->CreateBody(body); It says that the expression is not assignable.

Comment: Yeah, I really wasn't sure about that second example. Edited again, give that a try.